# flash builder navigator.popToFirstView. the first view instance created again

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder

whenever I use "navigator.popTOFirstView"

the topView always created again..

how can i remove previous or re-use that?

the problem is memory leak.. that instances are not deleted and created again and again..

please help me ~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Answer.

I used below, and reuse that class(FirstView).

destructionPolicy = "never";